# why can I not reach my machine remotely?

Tags: windows, networking, remote

I have a private network set up in my office lab.  There is one machine that is behaving strangely.

I am able to reach all other machines on the lab network from the machine, but for whatever reason, other machines cannot reach it.  Even attempting to ping the machine is not working.

The machine in question is running windows 7.  does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Is there a firewall on the machine?  If so, is it configured to allow access?  Are all the devices connected the same way to the network?  What is the problem machine plugged into?

Comment: the problem machine is plugged directly into the same switch as another machine that is having no problems.  I am waiting on a colleague to let me know if the firewall is active, but I can't imagine the firewall would block ping.

Comment: @ewok Actually, ICMP (which is used for ping) is blocked in the Windows 7 firewall by default: http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7

Comment: @uSlackr the firewall was the problem.  i had my colleague disable it and it works.  please post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: I can imagine it...  While you are at it verify the IP settings ( subnet mask, gateway, etc)  on the problem machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to ensure the firewall is not blocking access.  Been there, done that one...